# Adding objects to array without duplicating nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, duplicates

```
if (checkFields.is(':checked')) {
    filtersText = '';
    checkFields.each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            var category = $(this).data('filter-category');
            endpoint += '&filter[' + $(this).data('filter-group') + '][]=' + category;
                if (filtersText !== '') {
                    filtersText = filtersText + ', ';
                }
            filtersText = filtersText + category;
            // find parent

            var treeParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.js-filter__group--title').text(); // 'Region'
            var treeChild = $(this).next('label').children('.js-filter__group__drop--title').text(); // 'London'

            // WORKINGS START HERE!!
            var mapSettings = [];

            mapSettings = [
                {parent: treeParent, children: [treeChild, treeChild]}, // {parent: 'Region', children: ['London', 'Birmingham', 'Manchester']},
                {parent: treeParent, children: [treeChild]}, // {parent: 'League', children: ['League 1', 'League 2', 'Premier']},
            ];
        }
    });
}
```

Figuring out the best way to avoid duplicates when adding objects to an array:

**Data set and requirements:**

- List of dropdowns (treeParent) with input fields (treeChild) in them for filtering
- need to add objects to array mapSettings **WITHOUT**:

  1. duplicating objects added with the same 'parent' name
  2. duplicating items in the array 'children

Comment: If you can create a demo fiddle, it would be helpful to us to solve it

Comment: If an object with parent and children who already have values in mapSettings, it must be inserted without duplicates or igonorado values?